# how can i obtain a drupal 7 path alias

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

hello everyone i am trying to code a block for drupal 7 using php to fill out a part of an iframe code that will be depend on the current nodes URL Alias.

for example: `<iframe height="70px" width="70px" src="<?php $path; ?>"></iframe>`

however i cant get this working using the following to set the $path variable:

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($nid)

$path = drupal_lookup_path('source', $path, $path_language);
```

i have PHP enabled on the site but i refrain from using it on content, everynow and then on blocks

EDIT

I managed to get this working a little bit better using the following:

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.arg(1));
```

however i noticed that the base url doesn't get included, not a big deal since i know what it is and it is something that will not change, however if there was a way to obtain it in php i would like to know.

Comment: I think it matters what part of the template process you are trying to do this in. you can do print_r($node) to see if the node variable is populated wherever you're trying this. $node may be set, but $nid I don't think is a system standard.

Comment: not in the template, it would be a block and i would tell drupal to display this block in certain pages. print_r($node) didnt work for me. thanks though i had a feeling that $nid was mean for template and modules and not for content/blocks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [url() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) and flag it to return an absolute URL:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid  = arg(1); 
  $path = url('node/' . $nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
}
```